# How to read german date into pandas datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have an excel file with a column date like these:

```
28.02.2022 00:00:00
```

What I want is to get it to datetime format without the hour.

I use this and this gives me an error "time data does not match data":

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%Y')
```

I can't find my error since the format seems to be right. I really appreciate every help.:)

Comment: @AlessandroTogni Yes.

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)` should be enough

Comment: @mozway Thanks, I used your solution and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your `format=` should be

```
'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

and not

```
'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%Y'
```

(which has a duplicate `%Y`).

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('28.02.2022 00:00:00', format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
Timestamp('2022-02-28 00:00:00')
```

Whether or not you care about the time part in the data is another thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).date()
```

Something like:

```
str(pd.to_datetime('28.02.2022 00:00:00').date())
```

would return:

```
'2022-02-28'
```